# Changing StoreKit Configuration for In-App Purchases: Debug to Release

Tags: ios, storekit

I am currently utilizing StoreKit for testing in-app purchases and have included a store kit configuration file that is synced from the App Store. Do I need to change the 'Edit Scheme' and set the StoreKit configuration to 'None' before releasing on the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to edit the scheme. If you will note, the setting for "StoreKit Configuration" is on the Options tab for the "Run - Debug" setup. If you look at the "Archive - Release" setup there is no Options tab and there is no setting for "StoreKit Configuration".

In other words, the "StoreKit Configuration" setting does not apply when you archive your app so you do not need to change it. It only needs to be changed if you wish to change the behavior while running the debug version of your app.